# SAX Parser in android loading with image and text

Tags: android, parsing, saxparser

I want to parse it through SAX Parser and the load the image through url and pass it to the next activity to show. But am failing to do so if any can help me out or give me some reusable code then it would be grateful. here is my xml file. Here is my parsed data class and adapter class don't to add items to arraylist. PLease help.

PARSEDDATA CLASS

public class ParseData extends DefaultHandler 
{
    boolean title , cost , pubDate , link = false;

```
private String temp = "";

ArrayList<String> arrtitle = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> arrcost = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> arrpubDate = new ArrayList<String>();

ArrayList<String> arrlink = new ArrayList<String>();



//---------START ELEMENT----------//

@Override
public void startElement(String uri , String localName , String qName , Attributes attributes) throws SAXException 
{
    super.startElement(uri, localName, qName, attributes);

    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        title = true;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("cost"))
    {
        cost = true;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {
        pubDate = true;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
    {
        link = true;
    }
}
//--------END ELEMENT----------//

@Override
public void endElement(String uri , String localName , String qName) throws SAXException 
{
    super.endElement(uri, localName, qName);
    if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("title"))
    {
        title = false;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("cost"))
    {
        cost = false;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate"))
    {
        pubDate = false;

    }else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("link"))
        link = false;
}

@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length)throws SAXException 
{
    super.characters(ch, start, length);


    if(title)
    {

    }

    if(cost)
    {

    }

    if(pubDate)
    {

    }

    if(link)
    {

    }
}
```

}

BINDADAPTER CLASS

public class BindDataAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

```
ArrayList<String> title;

ArrayList<String> cost;

ArrayList<String> pubDate;

LayoutInflater inflater;



//---------DEFAULT CONSTRUCTOR-----------//

public BindDataAdapter()
{

}


//-------PARAMETERIZED CONSTRUCTOR------//

public BindDataAdapter(Activity activity , ArrayList<String> title , ArrayList<String> cost , ArrayList<String> pubDate)
{
    this.title = title;

    this.cost = cost;

    this.pubDate = pubDate;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}


@Override
public int getCount() 
{
    return title.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position , View convertView , ViewGroup parent) 
{

    if(convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row , null);
    }

    TextView textViewtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.type);

    TextView textViewcost = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.cost);

    TextView textViewdate = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);





    return convertView;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Use same code that you are using for parsing the data and For image, add extra variable and parameter as explaine [in this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3178883/asynchronous-image-loader-on-listview-android) and use ImageLoader class to load images in the listView.

You ca also refer [this](http://androidimageloader.com/), [Android lazy image loader example](http://www.android-ever.com/2011/06/android-lazy-image-loader-example.html) and [Loading Remote Images in a ListView on Android](http://ballardhack.wordpress.com/2010/04/05/loading-remote-images-in-a-listview-on-android/) Link for reference.

Feel free to comment.

Comment: @ayansinha: You have to parse the ImageURL from the xml and then display it in to the ListView using ImageLoader as i have given example in to my answer.